# is possible to enable two-factor authentication in ABP.IO Framework..?

Tags: abp

facing issue to enable the two-factor authentication in ABP.io with identity server 4
How to modify the logic of identity server 4 controllers..?
now identity server 4 controllers in metadata, so I cannot edit this controllers

Comment: Yes, it's possible, check the [link](https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/latest/modules/account#two-factor-authentication).

Comment: @EngincanVeske the link is for abp commercial, any way to force 2fa for all users in abp framework. Any settings in db or code config ?

Comment: no, it's the commercial feature. You need to implement it manually in the free version.